# Double Click to Make Working Links on IOS for iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, iframe

I am using html code using iFrame.
This make ios to click twice on making links workable.
When I remove the iFrame, it works well on single click.

However, I have to make the links workable on ios on single click having iFrame.

I prefer the solution using css rather than javascript or jQuery.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using safari on IOS? If so, [this](https://gist.github.com/PocketNinjaDesign/689e16e412a88dfd36dd08b26bebcacf) might be an explanation as to why it is happening.

Also, I don't quite know the proper sollution as to how to get an element in an iFrame using css. But it can be done with js as described right [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_element_iframe.asp)